# How to implement Barrier like functionality in node?

Tags: node.js, express, promise, barrier

I am writing a small API. I have written a small piece of code that basically sends an email and a SMS upon receiving the request. Now i want for the email and SMS both to be send before replying with a success code or error. One way to do this is synchronously, using promises or async/wait. But how can i do it asynchronously and still make sure that both tasks have completed before responding to the request. I was thinking we can do it using a barrier. Is there a better way to do it or should i do it using promises ?

Comment: Promises and async/await are not synchronous.  That's why it's call **a**sync.